# Display Multiple images uploaded with FilePicker.io

Tags: php, ajax, filepicker.io

I have been trying to implement the FilePicker.io API to let users upload images on a product page and I have been desperately trying to display the uploaded files (images only) on the page. The Filepicker opens fine, I can upload the image successfully etc, so after uploaded a file I can see in the console that I have an object with some information about the newly uploaded file. All I want now is to display the images, using $.ajax POST ? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v2/filepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  filepicker.setKey('l5uQ3k7FQ5GoYCHyTdZV');

    $('#big-freaking-button').click(function() {
    filepicker.pickAndStore({},{location: 's3'},function(fpfiles){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fpfiles));
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="row button">
    <a href="#" id="big-freaking-button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Filepicker Something</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

Ok I have manage to display one image... using the filepicker  and a placeholder. Now can any one tell me how to display multiple images as a gird?

[Working Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/bgpwwh1s/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#big-freaking-button').click(function(){ 

        filepicker.pickAndStore({},{location: 's3'},
            function(fpfiles){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(fpfiles));
        }, 
        function(Blob) {
            console.log(Blob); 
            console.log(Blob.url); 

            $.ajax("/upload", {
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    product_id: {{{ $product->id }}},
                    img_path: Blob.url
                }
            });
        }
    )
};
```

You will need to store the URL somewhere for this to work, then in your HTML you can perform a foreach to display the images:

```
<?php foreach($product->images as $image){ ?>
    <img src="{{{ $image->img_path }}}">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tryed using that code but seems I have an error, It gives me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {' at this line 'product_id: {{{ $product->id }}},' does your code include the storage of the URL or do I have to add that?

Comment: You will need to store the URL somewhere for this to work.

Comment: Ok, sorry but how do you store the URL? is there any way to retrieve the URL link logged in the console?